# Why am I getting $ is not defined error?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, call

I need to call a php file through ajax. I tried following:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

setInterval(function(){
test();
},3000);

function test(){     
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "GetMachineDetail.php",
    data: "{}",
    success: function(response){
         alert("suceccess");}
    });
}
```

It's simple javascript jquery calling... But I've got an ajax not found error.

***Question:*** How could I solve this issue?

Comment: jQuery is required for `$.ajax`, where do you include the lib

Comment: try **jQuery.ajax**, well as the above comments , are you including jQuery file or not ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Answer (score 2):

Need to include jquery library in HTML.

It's giving error just because using jquery without library.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a (poorly named) function supplied by the jQuery library. You need to include that library in your page before you try to use it.

You can get it from the [jQuery website](http://jquery.com/download/) (where you will also find instructions on how to use third-party hosted versions).